# My reputation is not increasing?

Tags: discussion, support

I am rather new in participating answering questions in SO, so pardon me if I am asking silly question. From today afternoon my reputation is not increasing, although my answers were being accepted/up-voted. For example my last [answered  question] got 10 up-vote, but no increase in rep.[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23655767/differences-between-c-and-c-array-size-is-not-honored/23655813#23655813) I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Congratulations on hitting the daily reputation cap. You can gain up to 200 a day from Upvotes, as the [help] article, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) explains.

Comment: As you can see, you have gained 260 rep today (so far). You will not gain any more rep from the activities listed - accepts, association bonus and bounties are not subject to this limit, so if any of these occur, you will gain more reputation, but not otherwise.