# Why is my reputation not visible after the association bonus?

Tags: support, bug, reputation, reputation-history, association-bonus

When I logged in today to Stack Overflow, I saw a +404 reputation points gain on "Recent Achievements" button. When I clicked on it, I found +100 reputation is gained (as association bonus) for all four communities on Stack Exchange each those I am associated with.

All other communities except Stack Overflow was showing the gain correctly. This combine makes +300.

Stack Overflow on other hand only shows a total of 200. I do not remember exactly, but it was around 193 before that. Hence the gain is only +7.

Why are reputation points not fully updated after the association bonus?

I read [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254835/my-reputation-is-not-increasing). It says "hitting the daily reputation cap" of 200 is the reason. Is this cap per community or for entire Stack Exchange? It must be per community as for other three communities there is +300 increase in reputation points.

[Another question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313786/why-my-reputation-was-not-correctly-updated) does not match with my scenario I guess.

If for any reason, +100 reputation gain was not applicable for Stack Overflow, why only +7 is gained. IMHO, it should be fully added or fully cancelled.

[image: Recent Achievements]

In below image, it shows total reputation is 200.

[image: Reputation]

In below image, it **was showing total reputation 300** for Stack Overflow few time back. Now, it is showing 200.

[image: Change in reputation from 300 to 200]

Look at tooltip in below image. It is still showing 300 reputation.

[image: Tooltip]

### Update 1

For [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286459/retrocomputing-reputation-bug) question, issue was automatically resolved after 4-5 days. So I will wait now.

### Update 2

This is still not corrected. Please suggest what my next step should be?

Comment: The daily rep cap isn't an issue, that is for a single site only.

Comment: Also note that the rep cap _ignores_ the association bonus, so even if you had hit the cap, the rep would still be yours.

Comment: Honestly, it's probably just a calculation error- The next time your rep is recalculated, it should correct itself. On that note, I'm not sure what triggers a rep recalc, so I don't know how long you have to wait. I think Community Managers can trigger a recalc, I don't recall if moderators can.

Comment: Also, related on MSE: [Retrocomputing Reputation Bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286459/retrocomputing-reputation-bug)

Comment: @Kendra: This is not yet corrected. What should I do next? Should I flag the question to bring it to moderator attention? Should I remove "discussion" tag and add "bug" tag? or else?

Comment: I would edit your question with an update that this is ongoing, and I would consider adding the bug tag. Editing will bump the question, and the bug tag will make sure it's on the dev's radar.

Comment: I can't actually do any of that, since I don't have enough rep. There are no suggested edits on Meta, so to edit another person's post, you need 2k rep. I only have 500.

Comment: That, or hope someone with 2k+ that read the comments comes along and helps you out. I think the chances of that aren't too great, though, so you're probably better off going ahead and making the changes yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed automatically, I can see the corrected reputation today.

I will note down the steps just in case someone else face this issue: -

- Wait for 7-10 days, this may get corrected automatically due to some trigger as mentioned in linked questions in my post.
- If it does not happen, post a question on meta. Do NOT use `bug` tag initially. Wait for few days.
- If this still does not reflect, add a tag `bug` to your question because your case MAY BE different than this. Wait for few days.
- Flag the question for moderator attention which I was planning to do after 4-5 more days of waiting.