# Why does the reputation graph indicate 100 more reputation?

Tags: bug, reputation, reputation-history

In my this account of Stack Overflow, my reputation has decreased by 100. It shows nothing on the reputation changes page.

See the image given:

[image: This].

In reputation change, it shows 440 reputation, but on the profile it shows 340. Why is this so? If I have a flag on any of my answer or question, then why do I see 440 reputation in the graph?

Comment: This is a repost of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70819648/why-is-my-stackoverflow-account-reputation-less-by-100

Comment: The discrepancy appears to be related to a 100 point Association Bonus.  It won't make any difference to your (reported) question ban.

Comment: Sambhav - Yes, I know.  I am telling >>other people<<.   Because there is a vote-to-close / migrate on your other ticket.  And your repost is relevant to what happens there ...

Comment: probably a spam flag on one of your posts. Those lead to -100 in rep but the graph has a long standing bug for not updating.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269653/why-did-i-gain-lose-reputation-can-i-audit-my-reputation-history/269654?r=SearchResults&s=1|11.1281#269654

Comment: also related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337343/why-is-my-reputation-not-visible-after-the-association-bonus

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have a -100 penalty on 2022-01-15, due to a post of yours being deleted as spam. That penalty is not being shown on your reputation graph. You should be able to see this penalty on [your reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17133283/sambhav-khandelwal?tab=reputation), but you will need to check the "show removed posts" checkbox which is at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @Sambhav Note that that option (and subsequently, the penalty) is only visible to you and diamond moderators like Makyen.